# Angular 2 ngClass both array and object syntax together?

Tags: angular, ng-class

In angular 1.x, I can use a combination of the array and object syntax in the same statement, like this:

```
<div ng-class="[classNameFromController, {'show' : booleanFromController}]"></div>
```

The same does not work in Angular 2 with the same approach:

```
<div [ngClass]="[classNameFromController, {'show' : booleanFromController}]"></div>
```

I can't find anything that suggests it can be done.

What gives?

Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

From the docs:

```
<some-element [ngClass]="stringExp|arrayExp|objExp">
```

which means one of `stringExp|arrayExp|objExp` (but not two of ;-) )